# Strange p-value histogram for differential gene expression analysis

Tags: rna-seq, differential-expression, kallisto, p-values

I'm trying to perform pretty standard differential expression analysis using RNA-seq data.

I've used [Kallisto](https://pachterlab.github.io/kallisto/) to perform RNA quantification and am using [Sleuth](https://pachterlab.github.io/sleuth/) to perform the differential expression analysis.

I have 2 conditions that I'd like to compare, which is stored in the `metadata`:

```
> metadata
    sample cell replicate batch                   path
1:  Base-1 Base         1   1   /path/to/Batch1/Base-1
2:  Base-2 Base         2   2   /path/to/Batch2/Base-2
3:  Base-3 Base         3   2   /path/to/Batch2/Base-3
4:  Test-1 Test         1   2   /path/to/Batch2/Test-1
5:  Test-2 Test         2   2   /path/to/Batch2/Test-2
6:  Test-3 Test         3   3   /path/to/Batch3/Test-3
```

I'm attempting to test for differentially expressed genes between the `Base` and `Test` cells while controlling for `batch` (the sequencing batch). The R code to do this is adapted from [Sleuth's manual](https://pachterlab.github.io/sleuth_walkthroughs/pval_agg/analysis.html):

```
sleuth_obj = sleuth_prep(
    metadata,
    extra_bootstrap_summary = TRUE,
    num_cores = 1,
    target_mapping = transcripts_genes, #ENSEMBL information mapping transcripts to genes
    aggregation_column = "ens_gene"
)

# smooth raw Kallisto abundances
sleuth_obj = sleuth_fit(sleuth_obj, ~cell + batch, "full")

# fitting error measurements on reduced model
sleuth_obj = sleuth_fit(sleuth_obj, ~batch, "reduced")

# compare models to calculate differentially expressed transcripts
sleuth_obj = sleuth_lrt(sleuth_obj, "reduced", "full")

# extract results
sleuth_table = as.data.table(sleuth_results(
    sleuth_obj,
    'reduced:full',
    'lrt',
    show_all = FALSE
))
sleuth_table_tx = as.data.table(sleuth_results(
    sleuth_obj,
    'reduced:full',
    'lrt',
    show_all = FALSE,
    pval_aggregate = FALSE
))
```

To check the quality of the null hypothesis, I've checked the p-value histograms of the gene-level and transcript-level analyses, and I get the following:

[image: Gene-level p-value histogram]
[image: Transcript-level p-value histogram]

Neither of these plots show well-behaved p-values, which makes me question the validity of the reduced model. How can I go about adjusting my analysis to get more reliable results?

## Edit following from @swbarnes2's answer:

I've used `fdrtool` to create an empirical null model of Sleuth's likelihood ratio test.

```
library(fdrtool)
local_fdr_txs = fdrtool(so$tests$lrt$`reduced:full`$test_stat, statistic="normal")
```

Which gives the following plots:

[image: fdrtool]

Plotting the distribution of these p-values produces:

[image: pvalues after fdrtool]

This still has a hump, but looks more anti-conservative than before.

My remaining question is about whether I can use `fdrtool` to model the null hypothesis as normal, since I'm not certain about the distribution for Sleuth's likelihood ratio test

Comment: what do mean by null hypothesis as normal ? Anyway, a good question +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that using the Wald test instead of the Likelihood Ratio Test produced very different results with respect to the p-values.

```
sleuth_obj = sleuth_prep(
    metadata,
    extra_bootstrap_summary = TRUE,
    read_bootstrap_tpm = TRUE,
    num_cores = 1,
    target_mapping = transcripts_genes,
    aggregation_column = "ens_gene"
)

# same model of covariates
sleuth_obj = sleuth_fit(sleuth_obj, ~cell + batch, "full")

# using Wald test instead of LRT
sleuth_obj = sleuth_wt(sleuth_obj, "cellLT1", "full")

# extract results
sleuth_table_genes <- as.data.table(sleuth_results(sleuth_obj, 'cellLT1', 'wt', show_all = FALSE, pval_aggregate = TRUE))
sleuth_table_txs <- as.data.table(sleuth_results(sleuth_obj, 'cellLT1', 'wt', show_all = FALSE, pval_aggregate = FALSE))
```

[image: Wald test gene-level]
[image: Wald test transcript-level]

The p-values are different, but surprisingly the rankings of the genes aren't too different from each other.

[image: LRT vs Wald]

Answer (score 1):

Try the protocol here for generating a different (smaller) dispersion estimate

https://www.huber.embl.de/users/klaus/Teaching/DESeq2Predoc2014.html#inspection-and-correction-of-pvalues

Comment: I found this previously, but where DESeq2 has its test statistic be normal, Sleuth detects differentially expressed transcripts using a likelihood ratio test. `fdrtool` can create an empirical null model on normal data, but is the test statistic from Sleuth's test normal?